# Removing duplicate values in a column in DevEpress Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, devexpress, spreadsheet

DevEpress Spreadsheet doesn't currently support "Remove Duplicate" function. I want to write a C# code to do this manually. I have a column of values. Some of them are duplicate and those duplicate values may or may not be adjacent. I want to remove corresponding row of duplicate values. I tried this code:

```
IWorkbook workbook = spreadsheetControl.Document;
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        CellRange range = worksheet.GetUsedRange();
        int LastRow = range.BottomRowIndex;
        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(LastRow));
        for (int i = 0; i < LastRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < LastRow; j++)
            {
                if (worksheet.Cells[i,0].Value == worksheet.Cells[j,0].Value)
                {
                    worksheet.Rows[j].Delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

It doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can you be specific about why it doesn't work?  What happens?

Comment: I doesn't remove non-adjacent duplicate values. In some cases, It removes unique values too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
  IWorkbook workbook = spreadsheetControl.Document;
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        CellRange range = worksheet.GetUsedRange();
        int LastRow = range.BottomRowIndex;
        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(LastRow));
        //Let's keep track of every value seen as we go through the rows
        var valuesSeen = new HashSet<CellValue>();
        //Rows marked for deletion
        var duplicateRows = new List<Row>();
        for (int i = 0; i < LastRow+1; i++)
        {
            string cellValue = worksheet.Cells[i, 0].DisplayText;
            //Returns false if the value already exists
            if (valuesSeen.Add(cellValue)==false)
            {
                //Mark this row for deletion since we've seen the value before
                duplicateRows.Add(worksheet.Rows[i]);
            }
        }
        //Delete all marked rows only after we're done identifying them.
        for (int index = duplicateRows.Count-1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            Row item = duplicateRows[index];
            item.Delete();
        }
```

Comment: I believe `var valuesSeen = new HashSet<CellValue>();` should be a hashset of strings though, since that's what you're adding with `string cellValue`.  Otherwise it looks good.  Glad it's solved.  I'll note DevExpress does give you the source code.  That last part (deleting rows backwards) looks odd to me.  Wondering if you just found a bug in their code and that gets around it.  Otherwise a `foreach` should work there.

Comment: No, As I mentioned before, When you delete rows from above, row indexes changes as you delete rows but your list is constant.

Comment: According to [this example](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15396/controls-and-libraries/spreadsheet/examples/rows-and-columns/how-to-delete-a-row-or-column-from-a-worksheet) from DevExpress, maybe using `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` will allow a `foreach`.  I'll just read their code at some point.  I agree there's index confusion going on.

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't remove non-adjacent duplicate values.

You have a bug in your loops.  The indexes are not accounting for the fact the collection is changing due to the `Delete` call.

You're also doing more work than necessary by going through all rows multiple times.

This creates a list of DevExpress `Row` objects that need to be deleted.  And it only goes through the rows once.

```
//Let's keep track of every value seen as we go through the rows
var valuesSeen = new HashSet<string>();
//Rows marked for deletion
var duplicateRows = new List<Row>();
for (int i = 0; i < LastRow; i++)
{
    string cellValue = worksheet.Cells[i, 0].DisplayText;
    //Returns false if the value already exists
    if (!valuesSeen.Add(cellValue))
    {
        //Mark this row for deletion since we've seen the value before
        duplicateRows.Add(worksheet.Rows[i]);
    }
}
//Delete all marked rows only after we're done identifying them.
foreach (var row in duplicateRows)
    row.Delete();
```

You may need to specify the namespace for `Row` given it's a fairly common class name.

In the above code I'm comparing the display text (not actual value).  Use `HashSet<CellValue>` instead of `HashSet<string>` if you don't want this.

Comment: It doesn't work properly.  It sometimes delete unique items too. And in some cases, it doesn't delete duplicates values. When there is empty cells between, the problem gets worse.

Comment: @Alex What's the data type for the column you're comparing?

Comment: Numbers. The code can put those duplicate values into a list but when deleting, it deletes one row by one  row and row index changes. We need to remove them at once. We may need to select all those rows and then delete them at once. I couldn't find any way to multiple select rows by code. I think I need to use "Press Ctrl" by code.